# How can I style the WordPress failure notice page?

Tags: css, wordpress

Is there a way I can style the WordPress failure notice page? Take a look at the screenshot below which shows an example of the page. This page is generated at various times and for various reasons. To generate the page, open 2 tabs in your browser and login to the same WordPress site on each tab.

1: log out of the site via the first tab you have open.

2: log out via the second tab.

You'll see the failure page.

[image: WordPress failure notice page screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach I took was to set up a custom die handler which gives you the option to style all 'die' messages.

```
// custom die handler
function get_custom_die_handler() {
    return 'custom_die_handler';
}

// hook the function
add_filter('wp_die_handler', 'get_custom_die_handler' );

// build a custom die handler
function custom_die_handler( $message, $title = '', $args = array() ) {
    // whatever you want the die handler to do
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the file `/wp-includes/functions.php` look for a function called

```
wp_nonce_ays
```

That is the function which outputs the error page. That is a core function, which is called by the action of `check_admin_referer`. You could try to hook into that action; the only problem is that it `die`s after `wp_nonce_ays` is called, so using `add_action` has no effect since it dies before it would trigger. However, luckily, `check_admin_referer` is a pluggable function, so you can make a function to override it. Our function will be an exact copy of `check_admin_referer` except one extra line of code is added to style it. Save the function, I called it styleFailPage.php, and put it in your `/wp-content/plugins/` folder.

```
<?php /*
* Plugin Name:Failure Styler
* Description:Adds a style element right before the failure notice is called
*/
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_logout' ) ) {
function check_admin_referer($action = -1, $query_arg = '_wpnonce') {
        if ( -1 == $action )
                _doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, __( 'You should specify a nonce action to be verified by using the first parameter.' ), '3.2' );

        $adminurl = strtolower(admin_url());
        $referer = strtolower(wp_get_referer());
        $result = isset($_REQUEST[$query_arg]) ? wp_verify_nonce($_REQUEST[$query_arg], $action) : false;
        if ( !$result && !(-1 == $action && strpos($referer, $adminurl) === 0) ) {
//this is the line I added:
echo "<style>body {background:red !important;}</style>";
                wp_nonce_ays($action);
                die();
        }
        do_action('check_admin_referer', $action, $result);
        return $result;
}

}
?>
```

This will make invalid HTML because you have to end up inserting the `<style>` info ABOVE the doctype declaration, however AFAIK this is unavoidable without explicitly editing the core `wp_nonce_ays` function

Comment: This involves editing the core files. Not really an approach I wanted to take

Comment: Thanks for the edit. The problem with editing the core files is you will lose any updates you've made when upgrading the platform at a future date. This may be acceptable if you are a developer confident in your ability to make the updates again after upgrading but is unacceptable if you're developing a website for a client. As soon as WP 3.7 comes out and your client upgrades, you'll be getting emails and phone calls asking where the customisations have gone.

Comment: I found a good approach is to set up a custom die handler. Take a look at my anwser

Comment: Your idea is much better. I overthought it.

Comment: chiliNUT appreciate your help with this, it got me thinking!